# Adding an image to a tab bar item only shows up as a block

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar which should have an image for the selected index.

Below is a sample-image which sould be used inside my tab bar.

[image: tab bar image i want to add]

I have added it by selecting the connected view controller assigned to the tab bar item and replacing the image. However this is what actually appears on the screen.  The assigned graphics is not appearing on the tab bar.

[image: The middle icon]

Comment: pass your image with `.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)`

Comment: You'll need to share some code.

Comment: Where do I write that line of code? I don't have my tab bar controller set up to any custom class. @ReinierMelian

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to `Assets.xcassets`
2. Select your image
3. Show the `Attributes Inspector`
4. Change `Render As` value form `Default` to `Original Image`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

set your tabBarImage in assets folder, And set Render as original Image[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line `self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "icono-menu")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)` in your item `viewController` viewDidLoad

**something like this**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "icono-menu")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    }
```